# Magick++ Error: must specify image size

Tags: c++, imagemagick, magick++

Currently, I am trying to run a simple Magick++ program that opens an image file as per a tutorial's instructions:

```
#include <Magick++.h> 
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
using namespace Magick; 
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{ 
  InitializeMagick(*argv);

  Image image("chitanda.jpg");

  return 0; 
}
```

However, upon trying to execute it I receive the following error:

```
Caught Magick++ exception: testMagick: must specify image size `/test.bmp' @ error/raw.c/ReadRAWImage/136
```

I figured that this meant that I needed to specify the size of the image I am reading. I have tried that, and still got an error, then I decided to make an odd attempt, what if I tried to execute a useless program such as:

```
#include <Magick++.h> 
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
using namespace Magick; 
int main(int argc,char **argv) 
{ 
  return 0; 
}
```

Oddly enough, I get the same exact error message. What could be the cause? I have only recently began dabbling in C++, and I am even newer to Magick++. I've trawled the internet for an answer, but haven't found anything. I hope that someone here has an idea!

UPDATE 1: I should add that "test.bmp" is not a file or name I have heard, seen or touched every before. This is one of the reasons this is so confusing to me.

UPDATE 2: After going to bed upon giving up for the night, and trying again in the morning I was able to compile, and then execute the program without any errors. However, now the program doesn't do anything! I'll execute it with './testMagick.cpp' and even when I want it to do something visible, like print out a debug statement to the console -- I get nothing. If anything, without the error I am now even more confused.

Comment: What does your compile/link command look like? How are you running the program?

Comment: Where is `testMagick` defined? I'm guessing there's previous object artifices being linked. Try "clean build", or removing intermediate files

Comment: My compile/link command is the one Magick++ documentation suggested, which is: g++ 'Magick++-config --cxxflags --cppflags` -o testMagick testMagick.cpp `'Magick++-config --ldflags --libs'`. I should include that "test.bmp" is not a name I have seen, heard or touched _anywhere_. I am running the executable using ./testMagick.cpp.

Comment: Also, emcconville: what is a clean build, and how might I do that? As I said, I don't have much expertise in C++.

Comment: Updated the question with key info about the problem and a new development.

Comment: You need to execute `./testMagick` not `./testMagick.cpp` - you cannot execute the C++ source file, you must execute the compiled binary executable.

Comment: Try typing `file *` and then execute the one that says it's executable not the ones that say "C++ source/header file".

Comment: Mark Setchell, I have been using ./myProgram for every other one of my C++ programs. It has always worked. How come for this particular instance, it won't? Furthermore, if I do execute ./testMagick.cpp, I get first, a permission denied error, then using sudo, I get 'command not found'. I have always been omitting the extension .cpp since that is the source file, not the executable and it has always been working fine. I also tried 'file *' and executed the executable. Same issues.